# MySQL не получается создать триггер

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер, foreign-key

Есть 2 таблицы : 
1-я :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
INT id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, VARCHAR order_type, INT order_id);
```

2-я :

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
INT order_id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, VARCHAR order_type, INT user_id);
```

Надо чтобы при добавлении в таблицу orders нового товара, с user_id = id существующего юзера у юзера с id = user_id обновлялось поле users.order_type = orders.order_type. То, что я пытался :

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'update_trigger'AFTER INSERT ON 'orders' FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO users(users.order_type) VALUES (order_type) WHERE users.id = 
user_id;
END
```

Что я делаю не так?
При этом еще по идее order_type, id из orders должны ссылатся (быть внешним ключем) на users.order_id, users.order_type

БД - MySQL

Comment: insert вставляет _новую_ запись, никакого where у него быть не может, потому что where применяется для фильтрации _существующих_ записей. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: А вообще, вы уверены, что у вас все правильно со структурой таблиц. У вас один пользователь не может сделать более 1 заказа за всю жизнь. И вы вдобавок добавляете нового пользователя, когда создаете новый заказ. какие то странные у вас пользователи ...

Comment: ну, по условию задачи у одного пользователя может быть один заказ, мне нужно чтобы при добавлении в таблицу orders значений с user_id = users.id у юзера добавлялся то же товар, что и в поле orders.order_type

Comment: раз пользователь на момент добавления заказа уже существует, то надо использовать update, который меняет _существующую_ запись, а не insert, который создает _новую_ запись

Comment: Но даже в при таком условии у вас на лицо избыточность данных. вы данные о заказе храните и в заказе и в пользователе. можно сделать id пользователя в заказе внешним ключом на таблицу пользователей и объявить его уникальным. Все, задача "один пользователь - один заказ" обеспечена. Никакая информация о заказе в пользователе не нужна. Наличие заказа определяется во время получения данных по наличию соответствующей записи в заказах (используя left join, например)

Comment: А текущая ваша структура позволяет один и тот же заказ назначить нескольким пользователям, что еще более странно, чем требование одного заказа на пользователя

Comment: в БД хранятся автомобили, суть приложения - аренда авто, так что данный подход более чем уместен

Comment: Ок. тогда пишите UPDATE вместо insert. Но когда вы уже напишите большую часть приложения и вдруг выясниться, что клиент хочет арендовать машину заранее, причем одну в следующий понедельник, а другую в среду и окажется, что для работы с этим вам надо начисто переделать структуру БД и за ней все приложение,. Или вдруг начнут появляться машины, которые непонятно за кем числятся, не говорите, что вас не предупреждали. Просто хранение одних и тех же данных в двух местах рано или поздно приводит к проблемам противоречивости этих данных

Comment: спасибо за совет, подумаю над этим.